# String is not a function on window location href

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider:

```
$('.b').click(function(){
    var link = 'www.yahoo.com';
    window.location.href(link);
});
```

I expect it to open www.yahoo.com, but it says "string is not a function". Why?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V9Xat/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript/21396837#21396837

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Try-

```
window.location.href = link;
```

or

```
window.location.assign(link);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V9Xat/3/)

[Check out the syntax of **window.location** here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location).

Comment: Come on.. Explanation, link to API... Something ...

Comment: @FlorianF., of course! :)

Comment: It is worth noting that window.location.href can be used as a function in both IE and Edge, just not other browsers ([and it isn't the standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)).

Answer (score 11):

Try using:

```
window.location.href = link;
```

[MDN source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location)

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.href = link;
```

Use this.

Answer (score 0):

Either use:

```
window.location.href = link;
```

Or with `.replace();`:

```
window.location.replace(link);
```